onValueChange() is not calling using custom keyboard Jetpack compose
I am creating a GST calculator.For this,a custom keyboard is designed. Whatever the key is pressed in keyboard the value has to be update in the TextField(). This is working fine.
Now, I want that if user input any value proceeding with arithmetic symbol like +,-,* then it  automatically start doing calculations like in calculator app. This is vsimilar to TextWatcher() in EditText() that used in basic android programming.
Below is code I've tried so far.
@Composable
fun MyEditTextField(inputValue: String, onValueChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    var textState by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(text = inputValue)) }

    Column {
        BasicTextField(
            value = textState.text,
            onValueChange = {
                textState = TextFieldValue(text = it)
                onValueChange(it)
            },
            singleLine = true
        )
        OutputTextView(text = textState.text)
    }
}

@Composable
fun OutputTextView(text: String) {
    Text(text = text)
}

Calling of this code is
val tvCalculator = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
MyEditTextField(inputValue =tvCalculator.value )
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "inputValue" + it)
        }

in above code onValueChange(it) is not calling.
P.S. It is a read only TextField()

You can update the logic inside the MyEditTextField composable to parse the input string and perform calculations accordingly.
 @Composable
    fun MyEditTextField(inputValue: String, onValueChange: (String) -> Unit) {
        var textState by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(text = inputValue)) }
    
        Column {
            BasicTextField(
                value = textState.text,
                onValueChange = {
                    val newText = handleInputTextChange(textState.text.text, it)
                    textState = TextFieldValue(text = newText)
                    onValueChange(newText)
                },
                singleLine = true
            )
            OutputTextView(text = textState.text.text)
        }
    }

private fun handleInputTextChange(currentText: String, newText: String): String {
    // Append the new text to the current text
    val updatedText = currentText + newText
    
    // Check if the updated text ends with an arithmetic symbol
    if (updatedText.matches(Regex(".*[+\\-*/]$"))) {
        // If it ends with an arithmetic symbol, perform calculation
        return performCalculation(updatedText)
    }
    
    // Otherwise, return the updated text as is
    return updatedText
}

private fun performCalculation(expression: String): String {
}


onValueChange() is not calling in this
